# Saving time on clicking action button in shiny

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I have created a shiny app to save start time and and end time when I click these buttons. I have three buttons: `Start`, `End` and `Download`, this app is intended to save the time when I have clicked `Start` and `End` buttons and then save the file in `.csv` when I click `Download` button. But it is saving the time of Download button click. Please help me save the different time properly.

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Header"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("start", "Start"),
      tags$br(),
      actionButton("end", "End"),
      tags$br(),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  startTime <- eventReactive(input$start,{
    Sys.time()
  })

  endTime <- eventReactive(input$end,{
    Sys.time()
  })


  data <- reactive({data.frame(start    = startTime(),
                               end = endTime())})


  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "download.csv"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data(), file, row.names = F)
    }
  )

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use global variables would work. Example below (edited to use per-session global variable).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Header"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("start", "Start"),
      tags$br(),
      actionButton("end", "End"),
      tags$br(),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  starttime <- NULL
  endtime <- NULL

  observeEvent(input$start, {
    starttime <<- Sys.time()
  })

  observeEvent(input$end, {
    endtime <<- Sys.time()
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "download.csv"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      data <- data.frame(start=starttime, end=endtime)
      write.csv(data, file, row.names = F)
    }
  )

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Isn't using global variable in shinyapp a bad practice? If this shinyapp is intended to be used by multiple users and  since this global variables will be shared across different sessions wouldn't that impact what the intended application of this app is?

Comment: @SBista Yes if you want per-session global variable, it should be within the scope of the server function. I've edited my answer. Global variable is not a bad practice by itself.